# NSNumber property going to nil when app is closed

Tags: ios

I have a singleton object with the an `NSNumber` property called recordingNumber that I use to keep track of recordings I have within my app.  When the app is first opened, recordingNumber is set to zero and is incremented every time a new recording is saved to the app.  When I close my app down and then reopen, the number goes back to zero and every new recording overwrites an old recording.  How can I keep the property from going to nil when the app is open and closed?  I'm using core data to store all my recording files - should I create a separate entity to store this one value?

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber * recordingNumber;
```

Comment: Can you show how the storage (property?) for the NSNumber is declared? i.e. @property (yadda, yadda) NSNumber *byeByeNumber

Comment: I think you have to consider to use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Couldn't you just count your recordings?

Comment: Ah, so by "close the app down" you mean *quit* it. Not resigning active, correct?

Comment: @quellish yes sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I use the recording number to name my files.  Counting my recordings wouldn't be consistent when files are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist small amount of data between app instances, data can be stored in NSUserDefaults:

To persist data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.recordingNumber forKey:@"recordingNumber"] 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In app launch, read this back from NSUserDefaults

```
self.recordingNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"recordingNumber"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, the easiest is to create a plist that can contain the number and other app settings. The plist is read  or created with defaults when the app is opened, and the values are saved each time you update or when you close the app.

You  can also create a separate table in your core data to contain the number but it will be overkill unless your table structure actually needs a table to contain historical  summaries like MTD (month to date) and YTD totals.